# Vue - how to append components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a button that, once is pushed, adds a child component to my component. My code works, except that the HTML is being parsed as a string, here is the parent component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <li v-for="item in items">
      {{ item.component }}
    </li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props:{},
  data(){
    return { 
      items: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {},
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    addItem(){
      this.items.push({component: '<testcomponent />'})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And the child component is very basic:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Testing</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

So the problem with my code is that, every time i push the button, instead of loading every time a new instance of the child component, it will parse the HTML as a string: `'<testcomponent />'`. How can i fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the component name, and use `<component :is="item.component"/>` in the `v-for` as follows:

```js
const testcomponent = Vue.component('testcomponent', {
  template: '#testcomponent',
});

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  components: { testcomponent },
  data() { return {  items: [] } },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.items.push({ component: 'testcomponent' });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template id="testcomponent">
  <div><h1>Testing</h1></div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="addItem">Add</button>
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <component :is="item.component"/>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! I only have one problem now: i'm getting "InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('<testcomponent>') is not a valid name.", i think i'm defining the component in the wrong place

Comment: @Jack022 you're welcome, are you registering the component in the parent?

Comment: Yes, first of all i imported it with import testcomponent from "./testcomponents", and then i registered it in components:{}

Comment: Ok fine! I was making a typo. Damn. Thank you a lot! This is a perfect solution.