# Vuetify not showing when i use jQuery append

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vuetify.js

I'm having trouble using jquery append with vuetify. I can't write any vuetify code in my javascript. It wouldn't show me the vuetify code, but it should work. I think it has something to do with vuetify having to be restarted when you want to insert a new vuetify code.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    methods: {
        createList() {
            if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
                $('#lists').append(`
                <v-card width="374" class="mx-10 my-12" elevation="5">
                    <v-system-bar color="${this.color.hexa}" dark><b>${this.name}</b></v-system-bar>
                        <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation>    
                            <v-card-actions>
                                <v-text-field v-model="name" ref="name" class="mx-5" :rules="jobsTitleRules" label="Title" required></v-text-field>
                                <v-btn color="success" @click="addTitle">Add</v-btn>
                            </v-card-actions>
                            <ul style="padding: 0px;" id="jobs"></ul>
                        </v-form>
                </v-card>`);
            }
        },
    },
})
```

Searched everywhere and really can't find a solution. Anyone who can help?

Comment: jQuery's `append` function was designed to append jQuery code or **native** JS/HTML elements. You shouldn't use it for Vue/Vuetify components. I hope [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66089129/vue-how-to-append-components) of [these topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540219/append-vue-js-component-using-jquery) will help you

Comment: Yes, but there is some data to include, is there a way to get this data?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, jQuery [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) function was designed to add **native** HTML, native JS, or jQuery objects.

It is not possible to use it with Vue/Vuetify because you are trying to show virtual template components which are **not native**.

In your case you can use a list of [Vue dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).

First of all, you need to create your dynamic component (I simplified your template a little):

```js
const externalForm = Vue.component('external-form', {
  props: {
    name: String,
    color: String,
  },
  data() { 
    return {  
      internalName: this.name,
    } 
  },
  methods: {
    addTitle() {
      this.$emit("emit-title", this.internalName)
    }
  },
  template: `
  <v-card width="374" class="mx-10 my-12" elevation="5">
    <v-system-bar :color="color" dark><b>{{name}}</b></v-system-bar> 
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-text-field v-model="internalName" class="mx-5" label="Title"></v-text-field>
      <v-btn color="success" @click="addTitle">Add</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>`,
});
```

When you need to pass some data to component, you should use **props**. For internal data you can use **data** section. And if you need to return some data, you can **emit** some event.

Now let's see how we can use it in your main template. Assume you already have some list of `<v-list-item>` components. You need to add some items into the tail of the list. This way, by example:

```js
<v-btn @click="addItem" color="primary">Click here to add item</v-btn>
...
<v-list-item v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key">
  <component :is="item.component" v-bind="{...item.props}" @emit-title="pushToList"/>
</v-list-item>
```

And finally you need to define your main component:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      titles: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    pushToList(val) {
      this.titles.push(val)
    },
    addItem() {
      this.items.push({ component: 'external-form', props: { 
        name: 'Some name', 
        color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16) //Just a random color HEX
      }})
    }
  }
})
```

I hope now you can apply this method to your business logic.

[CodePen playground is available here.](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/GRGpGmo?)